# Fill array with prompt in JavaScript and use push method

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am learning arrays in JavaScript and I am using the foreach with the push method.

The following code is working as its supposed to:

```
    let numbers = [-1, -2, -3, 5, 6, 1]
    let pos = []
    let neg = []
    
    numbers.forEach(number => {
            if (number<0) {
            neg.push(number)
        } else {
            pos.push(number)
        }
        
        })
        
       document.write("Number of positive numbers are: "+pos + "<br>" + "<br>")
       document.write("Number of negative numbers are: "+neg)
```

But I want to replicate this with a prompt, instead of hard coding the values in the array. And end the prompt with a 0.
The code I attempted is the following, but the variables pos and neg are never evaluated', this is my code:

```
    let numbers = []
    let pos = []
    let neg = []

    let number = parseInt(prompt("Input nr"))
    document.write("Your input nr was: " + number + "<br>" + "<br>")
    
    while (number != 0) {

        number = parseInt(prompt("Input nr"))
        document.write("Your input nr was: " + number + "<br>" + "<br>")

        numbers.forEach(number => {
            if (number<0) {
            neg.push(number)
        } else {
            pos.push(number)
        }
        
        })

    }

    document.write("Number of positive numbers are: "+pos + "<br>" + "<br>")
    document.write("Number of negative numbers are: "+neg)
```

What have I done wrong in my code?

Comment: Take the `forEach` bit out, your `while` loop is kind of its replacement..

Comment: you are looping over numbers array to find pos and neg numbers but you never push the number to numbers array. also if you are not using the numbers array you dont need to push number in it every iteration, you can just use a condition to check if the number is positive of negative to push to its respective array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push the number into numbers array

```
numbers.push(number)
```

```js
let numbers = []
    let pos = []
    let neg = []

    let number = parseInt(prompt("Input nr"))
    numbers.push(number)
    document.write("Your input nr was: " + number + "<br>" + "<br>")
    while (number != 0) {

        number = parseInt(prompt("Input nr"))
        numbers.push(number)
        document.write("Your input nr was: " + number + "<br>" + "<br>")
    }
    numbers.forEach(number => {
            if (number<0) {
            neg.push(number)
        } else {
            pos.push(number)
        }
        
    })

    document.write("Number of positive numbers are: "+pos + "<br>" + "<br>")
    document.write("Number of negative numbers are: "+neg)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `push` method to push it in the numbers array:

```js
while (true) {
    let number = parseInt(prompt("Input number"))
    // end on zero
    if (number == 0) {
        break
    }
    // invalid number check
    if (isNaN(number)) {
        alert("Invalid number, try again.");
        continue;
    }
    document.write("Your input nr was: " + number + "<br>" + "<br>")
    // push it to the array
    numbers.push(number)
}
// forEach afterwards
numbers.forEach(number => { /* ... */ })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code to below

```js
let numbers = []
    let pos = []
    let neg = [];
let number;
   // let number = parseInt(prompt("Input nr"))
    //document.write("Your input nr was: " + number + "<br>" + "<br>")
    
    while (number != 0) {

        number = parseInt(prompt("Input nr"))
        document.write("Your input nr was: " + number + "<br>" + "<br>");
        
        //-----------------------//-
          if(number >0){
            pos.push(number);
          }else if(number < 0){
            neg.push(number);
          }
      //-----------------------//-


    }

    document.write("Number of positive numbers are: "+pos + "<br>" + "<br>")
    document.write("Number of negative numbers are: "+neg)
```